# Why/How can Hydrophobic things pass the lipid bilayer?

Tags: human-biology, biochemistry, cell-biology, cell-membrane, membrane-transport

I’m just looking for a simple answer for this question. I’m in Bio 10, and don’t know the in depth stuff. So the lipid bilayer is hydrophilic and the ends, but hydrophobic in the middle; so how can the hydrophobic substance pass through the phosphate head in the first place? If hydrophobic substances can pass through, shouldn’t hydrophilic substances be able to pass through as well? TIA